# Can i validate user in my application by using google login?

Tags: javascript, authentication

I have developed tower of hanoi game in java script. Now, I want to make login page for the same but, I don't want to validate username and password by using my database information.

My requirement: I want to allow to play game to any user who are having google account. can i do this?

if yes, how?
please help.
would be grateful for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll provide you the direct link for OAuth 2.0 for Client Side Applications (i.e. javascript apps)

https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2UserAgent

Answer (score 0):

use openID - http://openid.net/add-openid/